# Types of Algorithms that Experiment with Solutions to Problems

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

I do not know the best way to word this. Apologies.

Essentially I am looking at segmenting/classifying patterned time-series data collected by sensors.

There are so many different ways to tackle this, that I'm contemplating writing a vast array of various generic functions/manipulations that can be made to the data, with a relatively small number of hyperparameters, and then handing that all to a genetic algorithm and let it come up with the best order/combination of those operations in order to get to optimize the classification/segmentation. Essentially just setting up an experiment and letting the solver play with different hammers, beakers, and duct tape until it gets to a solution. A lot of where I am sitting now is a "chicken or the egg" for binning, calculating, recombining, removing, etc.

Is there a better methodology out there, i.e. is this too ham-fisted? It's touching on reinforcement learning, but I think the genetic algorithm approach would be more preferable considering my current hardware constraints.

I'm effectively looking for the autogluon-like approach to solving this (throw everything in different combinations), but in a more rigidly-constructed, predictable manner.

I have been manually performing different operations to bin, calculate, extract, etc. on the data, but would like to write an all-encompassing experimentation engine that will work everything out itself.

Comment: What do the time-series look like? The hard part is determining what it means for two time-series to be "similar". Have you tried Levenshtein distance? Perhaps with a clustering algorithm?

Comment: Sorry, I was side tracked from this project at work. 
The time series are simply individual pulses of communication with a timestamp of when they were received and some parametrics such as Amplitude. I am trying to separate out the emitters since they are all non-cooperative in a noisy environment. They each have their own underlying structure and patterns in their communication, but I would like for my machine to learn how to separate them out automatically.